# CSS - paragraph - Do I need to set font-size: inherit?

Tags: css

I want that all my `p` tags inherit the font size of the body - which they do automatically if I don't declare a font size on them or nest them in a parent with a font-size declared.

But should I add `font-size: inherit` to the `p` inside my CSS? Would that bring me any advantages?

Answer (score 1):

No.  [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) is an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance), so having no `font-size` on an element is exactly the same as using `font-size: inherit;`.

Writing it out explicitly is actually *worse*, since if I saw that, I'd wonder what other rule it's supposed to override that I'm missing.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `font-size: inherit` helps you only in this case:

- You want that the `p`'s inherit the font size from body.
- All the `p`'s are direct children of `body`.
- However, some of them have `font-size` set by another rule in the stylesheet.
- By adding `font-size: inherit` with either higher priority or `!important` you can override that and make the `p`'s inherit it.
- Even then you could just remove the other rule.

So, you don't really need to put it there. And probably shouldn't, because less useless code is easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

No need of writing `font-size: inherit` for the `p` to inherit the font size of the `body`

`font-size: inherit` it was only needed to override another rule.

> For inherited properties, this reinforces the default behavior, For example:
>
> /* make second-level headers green */  h2 { color: green; }
>
> /* ...but leave those in the sidebar alone so they use their parent's
>   color */  #sidebar h2 { color: inherit; } Note that in this example
>   the h2 elements inside the sidebar might be different colors. For
>   example, if one of them were the child of a div matched by the rule

reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

Answer (score 0):

I kind of had the same question as I was working on an internal portal. What I understand is that there seems to be no specific advantage to the `font-size: inherit` property as the font size is inherited naturally. IE7 and earlier does not support the `inherit` value, so that is something you should know but it should not affect you for the font-size property.

There are properties like *margins* which are not naturally inherited, so the *inherit* value might be useful there. But I am not elaborating here as that would deviate too much from your question. Anyway, check out the CSS properties that are not inherited by default in order to know where to use inheritance. Check out this article http://www.impressivewebs.com/inherit-value-css/ for more information.